# How to color arrows based on direction in geom_path

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to color code arrows based on their direction using geom_path in ggplot2. I have multiple years of data in individual rows and want an arrow pointing from the earliest data point to the most recent, with color depicting the direction to make it even easier to interpret. The points are grouped by Lake_ID, and because there are multiple rows for each year I'm having trouble.

Here's the basic data:

```
    Lake_ID Year    Gear    psd BioVolume
    16  2012    EF  0.370967742 0.095585695
    16  2012    GN  1   0.095585695
    16  2012    TN  0   0.095585695
    16  2012    Whole   0.375   0.095585695
    16  2017    EF  0.214285714 0.100623115
    16  2017    GN  1   0.100623115
    16  2017    TN  0   0.100623115
    16  2017    Whole   0.179487179 0.100623115
```

[image: Basic Graph]

```
    ggplot(blg.dup.year,aes(BioVolume,psd,group=Lake_ID,label=Year))+
        geom_point(aes(BioVolume,psd,colour=Year))+theme_bw()+
        facet_grid(Gear~.,scales = "free_y")+
        labs(title="Bluegill PSD",y="PSD",x="Littoral BioVolume")+
        geom_path(arrow=arrow(angle=30,length=unit(0.1,"inches"),
            type="closed"),aes(group=Lake_ID))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you mean by direction is whether the arrow is pointing up or down here is one solution. 
Assign your original plot to a variable:

```
p1 <- ggplot(blg.dup.year,aes(BioVolume,psd,group=Lake_ID,label=Year))+
  geom_point(aes(BioVolume,psd,colour=Year))+theme_bw()+
  facet_grid(Gear~.,scales = "free_y")+
  labs(title="Bluegill PSD",y="PSD",x="Littoral BioVolume")+
  geom_path(arrow=arrow(angle=30,length=unit(0.1,"inches"),
                        type="closed"),aes(group=Lake_ID))
```

Get data from layers (your arrows are the second geom):

```
arrow_data <- layer_data(p1, 2)
```

Get the directions from the y axis and then assign a color based on the sign:

```
directions <- diff(arrow_data$y)[seq(1,nrow(arrow_data),2)]
colors <- case_when(sign(directions) == -1 ~ "red",
                    sign(directions) == 0 ~ "orange",
                    sign(directions) == -1 ~ "green", 
                    TRUE ~ "grey50")
```

You need to double the colors as ggplot requires a color for start and finish points.

```
colors <- rep(colors,each = 2)
```

And finally just add the color to the geom:

```
ggplot(blg.dup.year,aes(BioVolume,psd,group=Lake_ID,label=Year))+
   geom_point(aes(BioVolume,psd,colour=Year))+theme_bw()+
   facet_grid(Gear~.,scales = "free_y")+
   labs(title="Bluegill PSD",y="PSD",x="Littoral BioVolume") +
   geom_path(arrow=arrow(angle=30,length=unit(0.1,"inches"),
                         type="closed"),aes(group=Lake_ID), color = colors)
```

So for your example you would get:

[image]

Comment: Ideally the color would depict an increase or a decrease on the x-axis. I adjusted the code you gave me a little, and for the most part it's working well. There's one group that has four arrow segments and they aren't coloring properly. Here's the adjusted code:

Comment: 'point_data<-layer_data(p1,1)directions.p<-diff(point_data$x)[seq(1,nrow(point_data),2)]
colors.p<-case_when(sign(directions.p)==-1~"red", sign(directions.p)==0~"orange",sign(directions.p)==1~"green",TRUE~"grey50")
colors.p<-rep(colors.p,each=2)
p2<-ggplot(blg.dup.year,aes(BioVolume,psd,group=Lake_ID))+
  geom_point(aes(BioVolume,psd,colour=Year))+theme_bw()+
  facet_grid(Gear~.,scales = "free_y")+
  labs(title="Bluegill PSD",y="PSD",x="Littoral BioVolume")+
  geom_path(arrow=arrow(angle=30,length=unit(0.1,"inches"),type="open"),
            aes(group=Lake_ID),color=colors.p)'

Comment: I think the root of the problem is that there are single points, thus taking the difference in sequence doesn't work.

Comment: 426 2014 EF 0.155555556 0.590394261 -8.163782743
426 2014 GN 0.2 0.590394261 -8.163782743
426 2014 TN 0 0.590394261 -8.163782743
426 2014 Whole 0.13559322 0.590394261 -8.163782743
426 2015 EF 0.401709402 0.269850811 -8.295077669
426 2015 GN 1 0.269850811 -8.295077669
426 2015 TN 0.057142857 0.269850811 -8.295077669
426 2015 Whole 0.326797386 0.269850811 -8.295077669
426 2016 EF 0.136363636 0.439568743 -7.106322148
426 2016 GN 1 0.439568743 -7.106322148
426 2016 TN 0.129032258 0.439568743 -7.106322148
426 2016 Whole 0.148148148 0.439568743 -7.106322148

Comment: Also, sorry for the incorrect formatting, I'm not sure how to post with code in a comment.